# Are there any plans to relocate the Palestinian state, in order to ensure peace with Israel?

Tags: israel, palestine

Palestine (along with the Arab world) and Israel have been in conflict for many decades now and it seems that they would continue to be in opposition for the decades to come. No solution is acceptable to both sides and nobody seems to want to move things forward.

But what if Palestine was simply relocated? Surely the Arab countries (especially Saudi Arabia) have lots of empty land for Palestine to move to? Or, as an alternative, Palestinians could become citizens of another Arab country and form their own cities there. Have there been any such plans in the history of Israel/Palestine?

Comment: how about this question: " what if Israel  was simply relocated? e.g. in the US"?

Comment: This is pretty much a troll question, but you could give them the land that was historically the Philistines' land from which the name was drawn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is sort-of the opinion of many of the more hard-line staunch Zionists: the Palestinian people do not exist and are just Arabs, therefore there is no reason for there to be a Palestine state, and the Arabs should relocate to their Arab nations if they don't like things.

This is mostly a fringe view, though. And as far as I can find there are no real mainstream proposals or plans to execute this. One good reason for this is that forced relocation of people based on ethnic background or religion is literally the definition of ethnic cleansing. It would be a crime under international law.

Why don't many Palestinians leave voluntarily? Well, for the same reason that the Northern-Irish Catholics didn't migrate to the Irish Republic (or the Protestants to the Britain), or that many African-Americans didn't simply [migrate "back" to Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberia): they feel it's their right to live there. Migrating might be a practical solution, but the feeling of "injustice" is a very strong one.

In addition, people have their homes, land, families, and communities there. Relocating costs money, and keeping (extended) families together will be difficult. Keeping in touch with friends almost impossible. Migration even in the best of circumstances has a price.

And who's going to accommodate the millions of people? Saudi-Arabia might see them as "Arab brothers and sisters in distress" [like it does with the ~500,000 Syrian refugees living there](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/anhvinh-doanvo/europes-crisis-refugees_b_8175924.html), but is it really willing to accommodate more than 5 million Palestinians? While we can't know the answer for sure, I somehow doubt they'll just accept that (not without a lot of kafuffle anyway).

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is **no**. Palestinians overwhelmingly believe they have an equal or stronger claim to the land occupied by Israel. Some Palestinians, [particularly those who have settled in Latin America](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2017/03/palestinian-diaspora-world-return-170313090704251.html), are willing to compromise and accept a two-state solution that would permanently recognize Israel. However even they are united in the demand for some form of recognition for a state on the historical land of Palestine. They may also advocate for greater acceptance wherever they happen to live, but it is very unlikely that many would support any mass relocation plan.

Similarly, the official position of many Arab and other Muslim-majority countries is that the state of Israel is fundamentally illegitimate. While some (especially Jordan and Lebanon) have begrudgingly hosted large Palestinian refugee populations, they have no interest in permanently relocating Palestinians outside of the what they consider to be occupied Palestine.

The hypothetical proposal here might be compared to those for alternative Jewish homelands, such as in [Uganda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uganda_Scheme) or [Siberia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Autonomous_Oblast). While significant, these projects were never terribly popular or accepted by large numbers of Jews.

Comment: Let's also not forget that the Arabs weren't consulted at all when the west suddenly forced the State of Israel on them, triggering the mass migration of Jews from *around the world* to the region. Imagine how the local Saudis would react if muslims from around the world suddenly claimed they were citizens of Saudi Arabia too because of Mecca and demanded land there to live? After Nazi atrocities against the Jews were revealed, the west didn't know how to deal with it or the Jews in their own country. Their knee jerk reaction was to find some way to get rid of the Jews from their country.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was such a proposal in the form of the [Elon Peace Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Peace_Plan):

> The plan was originally proposed in 2002 by then-Israeli tourism minister Rabbi Binyamin Elon. It advocates the formal annexation of West Bank and Gaza by Israel, the Palestinians becoming citizens of Jordan, which would become a Palestinian state, with their final status to be negotiated. The Palestinian refugee camps would be dismantled, and the Palestinian refugees would be fully absorbed into their host countries. Elon and Moledet (Elon's party and the chief supporter of this plan) proposed that "Israel, the United States and the international community will allocate resources for the completion of the exchange of populations that began in 1948 and the full rehabilitation of the refugees and their absorption and naturalization in various countries".

The plan didn't seem to go anywhere, as of 2019.